# Xdebug loaded correctly in Ubuntu but var_dump/error handling not being over-ridden

Tags: php, xdebug

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 and as usual installed xdebug from the package manager. I've never had a problem after that with getting the formatted error messages and var_dumps to show up but this time they don't.

I ran phpinfo() and it is definitely loading it, and I even tried running some of the custom xdebug functions and all is working fine, but when I do a var_dump it comes up as though xdebug isn't installed. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

xdebug overloads the default `var_dump` function with its own, which means some settings may be carried over from the default PHP configuration.  Specifically, make sure `html_errors = On`.

It's also possible that the xdebug package added some non-default [configuration options](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display).    Specifically in this case, make sure `xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1`.

Comment: Nice one  - html_errors fixed it. Incidentally is that a new feature in PHP 5.3?

Comment: @pitch_invasion The default ini setting may have changed in php 5.3, but it's not a new setting, afaik.